# What is the reasoning behind the definition of relative entropy?

Tags: probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy

**I do not understand the notion of relative entropy.**

**Relative Entropy**. $D_{KL}(P||Q) = \sum_{i}^{}P(i)\log \frac{P(i)}{Q(i)}$.

I try to get some intuition why it looks the way it looks. I see that it works: if 
I take $Q=P$ then $D_{KL}(P||Q)=0$, so the distance between identical distributions is 0.

I tried to find some intuition in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence): *KL divergence can be interpreted as the expected extra message-length per datum that must be communicated if a code that is optimal for a given (wrong) distribution Q is used, compared to using a code based on the true distribution P*.

Very confusion description, and has no clue why it's actually $P(i)\frac{P(i)}{Q(i)}$.

I would appreciate if someone could give the reasoning about the definition of relative entropy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In information theory, relative entropy $D(P\|Q)$ is the number of extra bits required per letter on average to encode a source with a distribution $Q=(q_1,\dots,q_n)$ when the true underlying distribution is $P=(p_1,\dots,p_n)$. $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ---- ~~~~(*)$

The optimal expected compressed length subject to unique decodability (which is equivalent to the Kraft inequality $\sum 2^{-l_i}\le 1$) is  given by $$l_i^*=\log \frac{1}{q_i}.$$

Hence the optimal expected code length (per letter) when coding with $Q$ is 
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum p_i\log \frac{1}{q_i}
&=&\sum p_i\log \frac{1}{q_i}\\
&=&\sum p_i\log \frac{p_i}{p_i\cdot q_i}\\
&=& \sum p_i\log \frac{1}{p_i}+\sum p_i\log \frac{p_i}{q_i}\\
&=& H(P)+D(P\|Q).
\end{eqnarray}
Hence the statement $(*)$. It has got other interpretations in probability theory and statistics though.

Comment: In wikipedia it is also given that this KL Divergence shows that amount of information loss occurred while changing one distribution to another. How can we convert the no. of extra bits to percent of information loss?

Comment: As per your explanation `H(Q) = H(P) + D(P||Q)`. So probably, the information loss percentage is `100 * (H(Q)-H(P))/H(P)` or `-100 * (D(P||Q)/H(P))`. I hope I have interpreted your solution correctly!

Comment: @AnimeshPandey Yes, a good interpretation indeed when we regard entropy as a measure of information. Sorry for the late comment; I didn't notice your comment before.

Comment: @AnimeshPandey I don't know what bumped this to front page, but no, that equation (and your interpretation) is not right. Entropy of P and Q can be basically anything, but D(P||Q) is always positive.

Comment: @E-A: Since it's discrete here, entropy of $P$ (or $Q$) is always positive. However, there's a minor mistake in Animesh's comment that it should be $H(P\|Q)$, the cross-entropy of $P$ with respect to $Q$ (the LHS of the last equation of my answer), not $H(Q)$.

Comment: True about $\geq 0$, that s what I had in mind when I wrote the comment; the counter-argument stays the same though. Yes, indeed, it should be the cross entropy, and then it is correct. I would consider it a bit more than a minor mistake personally, but anyway, I left it as a note so that someone else passing by isn't confused and starts using that claim. Good answer on the original question by the way! I would have put the floors on l, and I don't think the lengths are necessarily unique (have it be uniform on A,B,C; 2 will be length 2 and other 1), but I think it captures the idea fine.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in [this](https://youtu.be/ErfnhcEV1O8) video. Cross entropy: `H(p,q)` can be interpreted as average message length that is sent to receiver based on predicted q distribution. In information theory, to compress given massage in most effective way, we look at its probability distribution. So basically, entropy: `H(p)` of the given probability distribution is our ultimate limit. For example, if I was sending 4 bits of data on average to receiver about the wheater of Istanbul, and also if I know the entropy of my message words is actually 3.2, it means that I can actually can compress my message more.

Thus, the difference between average message lenght that was sent and actual entropy of the message is equal to KL Divergence.

Edit: The person who gave me a down vote, please can you explain why?